# Merge .ass-subtitles into movie

Tags: subtitles

I produced a video which will include subtitles. The movie is edited in Premiere Pro and (currently) rendered to a .mov file. I've created subtitles with Aegisub which creates a .ass file in order to keep the existing font- and position settings.

Is there anyway in which I can merge the .mov and the subtitles together? I've tried many different programs but none of them seems working. The only one that worked a bit was SubMerge but that ignored the font-settings and positions of the subtitles.

Comment: can you not add the subtitles within Premiere Pro instead of using Aegisub?

Comment: This is not the purpose of the title tool in Premiere. Next to that it works not as handy as Aegisub.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles was very good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Will refer to Premiere Pro as PP and After Effects as AE from here on:**

**Here is a solution which requires AE** that *I think* works but can't test it because my demo of PP and AE has finished. Luckily for you, **they have trials for many products including AE which you [can download from their site](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=designweb_premium).** I contacted a friend of mine who works as a video editor about this and he mentioned something that sounded a lot like this method, but without the conversion I will mention. At least I'm pretty sure since some of what he said went over my head.

Anyways, he initially said that **.ass files are not compatible with Premiere Pro.** Luckily though he pointed out that **you can easily convert .ass files into .srt files, which can be imported into PP (CS4 and above).**

[**Here is a website that does this for free**](http://sub-converter.hostei.com/)

This is where he began to loose me, but mentioned using the analyze content feature to make sure the content roughly matches up with the video. The video below will explain more and clarified stuff for me.

[**Here is the video explaining how to do this and how to automate the process**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LAnZPDUOiI)

Comment: Not 100% the solution I was looking for. But I think there aren't much better alternatives as we speak.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry this is a bit late but I just found your question while doing research on this topic.

If you have access to After Effects, I've developed a script that can import .srt subtitle files (I think you can export .srt from Aegisub). You can download a trial at http://aescripts.com/pt_importsubtitles/

It preserves the timings but not the font or position, although these are easy enough to set in AE. Once imported you can drag the composition straight into Premiere Pro using Dynamic Link for compositing onto your movie.

I've also developed a script that can import .ass files into AE. It's primarily meant for subtitles with karaoke timings, but it should be able to import plain subtitles too.
http://aescripts.com/pt_ssakaraokeanimator/